# What is the short cut for opening method definitions in visual studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I would like to open a window that lists all the method definitions so that I can navigate to the one I am interested in. Eclipse does this very elegantly ; I think it is CTRl + O there.

Answer (score 0):

If you open the "Outline" window, I believe that will show you a method listing. Unfortunately I just removed 2008 from this PC so I can't look.

I know that F12 is the shortcut to go to a method definition if you have your cursor on it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>F</kbd> for File Structure. I usually keep it docked as a tab alongside Solution Explorer.